# Saving a file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, safari

I am trying to learn, how to create, write and save a `txt` file (in any directory) using `javascript`. All, I found was using `ActiveX` which works only in `IE`. Does anybody know how can it be done in `Chrome` or `Safari`?

Comment: Javascript shouldn't be dealing with the file system.  It's the language of the browser.

Comment: @duffymo these days, JavaScript as a language is hardly limited to the browser...

Comment: I agree w/ that, but still not for file system.  i'm guessing the OP is using it in the browser/sandbox and wondering why they're having trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Yes ActiveX works only in IE. Please take a look at [File System APIs of HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) which may help you

Answer (score 1):

Refer this link [downloadify](http://davidwalsh.name/downloadify).If you don't have any issues on Flash vulnerabilities in your application, you can go with this. This plugin internally uses flash file to create flat files(but limited to txt, excel and csv types) from javascript. Hence burden on server will be reduced thus increases the productivity and performance of the application.